# Twitter API can't authorize (Android)

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

Sorry for my english. I cant understand why I can't authorize in app. I use twitter documentation, but when I input login and password in twitter it nothing happens, callback in code not work.

Sorry about link in image, I have not 15 reputation

My **settings** in twitter:

[image http://take.ms/SQcRO](http://take.ms/SQcRO)

When I click this button it nothing happens:

[image http://take.ms/4Xo9R](http://take.ms/4Xo9R)

My code:

```
  TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);
    status.setText("Status: Ready");

    loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
    loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            Log.e("success", "success");
            // The TwitterSession is also available through:
            // Twitter.getInstance().core.getSessionManager().getActiveSession()
            TwitterSession session = result.data;
            // TODO: Remove toast and use the TwitterSession's userID
            // with your app's user model
            String msg = "@" + session.getUserName() + " logged in! (#" + session.getUserId() + ")";
            Log.e("msg", msg);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            status.setText("Status: Login Failed");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("error", "Login with Twitter failure", exception);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Make sure that the loginButton hears the result from any
    // Activity that it triggered.
    loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In debugger not enters in this line: `loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: Are you implementing this code inside an Activity or fragment ?

Comment: @BijeshPV inside activity